# How can I populate a column in Power Query (PowerBi) with values from another query based on conditions?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[This is the extracted data after some transformation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU57i.png)

[This is the final presentation I need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGxcz.png)

To illustrate my problem with an example:
In Image 1:

{[Date: 1/11/22, Plant_1: Car, Quantity_1: 2, Plant_2: Boat, Quantity_2: 2, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 2],

[Date: 1/11/22, Plant_1: Car, Quantity_1: 2, Plant_2: Boat, Quantity_2: 2, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 2],

[Date: 1/11/22, Plant_1: Car, Quantity_1: 2, Plant_2: Boat, Quantity_2: 2, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 2],

[Date: 2/11/22, Plant_1: Boat, Quantity_1: 1, Plant_2: Car, Quantity_2: 1, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 1],

[Date: 2/11/22, Plant_1: Boat, Quantity_1: 1, Plant_2: Car, Quantity_2: 1, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 1],

[Date: 2/11/22, Plant_1: Boat, Quantity_1: 1, Plant_2: Car, Quantity_2: 1, Plant_3: Plane, Quantity_3: 1]
}

I need to transform this into

{[Date: 1/11/22, Car: 6,Boat: 6, Plane: 6],

[Date: 2/11/22, Car: 3,Boat: 3, Plane: 3],}

I am wondering if there is a way to let cells in Image 2 take the SUM of values in cells of Image 1 under the condition: If the Date is same AND name of Plant is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if this works for you in powerquery

method 1: stack the columns using list.accumulate:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base_columns=1, groupsof=2, 
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(
    Combo, 
    #table({"Column1"}, {}),
    (state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1)
),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Column1", type date}, {"Column3", type number}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column2] <> null)),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Column2]), "Column2", "Column3", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

method 2: use two pivots in place of the list.accumulate

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base_columns=1, groupsof=2, 
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns), "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Inserted Integer-Division" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], groupsof), Int64.Type),
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Integer-Division", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], groupsof), type number),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Modulo",{"Index", "Attribute"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Modulo", type text}}, "en-US")[Modulo]), "Modulo", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Integer-Division"}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[#"0"]), "0", "1", List.Sum),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column1",{{"Date", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

method 3: grouping. Didn't bother to do that one

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am working on PowerBI though. Also, in your blue table, it would better illustrate my case if there are multiple rows of the same date.

Comment: Based on your screenshots you are apparently working in Power Query within Power BI. @horseyride has given you Power Query code.

Comment: I updated my picture to help you. The code does not need to change